# Create x amounts of lists using a for loop in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make 1 list for every item in this list, but the length of the list is based on user input, so that is why I'm using a for a loop.

#### My Idea:

```
listno = 0
for i in arialabel:
    a+str(listno) = []
    print(a+str(listno))
    listno+=1
```

My current problem is that you can't use operators in the names of variables.

Comment: `yourlists = []; for _ in range(howmany): yourlists.append([])`

Comment: Yes you should not use that, please provide more info of what you are doing.I would suggest you to simply make a list of list for that usage.

Answer (score 1):

Put your lists in a dictionary:

```
arialabel = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
prefix = "a"

lists = {}
listno = 0
for i in arialabel:
    lists[prefix+str(listno)] = []
    print(prefix+str(listno))
    listno+=1

print(lists)
```

Result:

```
a0
a1
a2
a3
{'a0': [], 'a1': [], 'a2': [], 'a3': []}
```

Example of usage:

```
lists['a3'].append("apple")
lists['a3'].append("pear")
print(lists['a3'])
```

Example result:

```
['apple', 'pear']
```

Comment: I think `a+str(listno)` was a variable OP was trying to define with that name, i.e. `a1`, `a2`, ... So in order to replicate what they want, you'd replace `a+str(listno)` with `"a"+str(listno)`. Also you can demonstrate how to get the value from the dict which might be helpful.

Comment: ah, ok. easy.  just change prefix